# How to model variables, where instead of values we observe intervals?

Tags: regression, references, ordinal-data, interval-censoring

Consider a case where instead of observing actual variable values, we are observing variable range. The possible range-values could be enumerated (i.e. could be a fixed set of values, for e.g. fixed age-group ranges) or could be observation specific (and might overlap).

<s>In the former case, the variable could be treated as an ordinal variable</s>. (Based on @whuber's comments, treating this variable as an ordinal variable seems an unnecessary restriction). Is anything similar possible for the latter case? Are there any other methods to analyze such data?

---

I am interested in general treatment for analyzing interval data variables - as an output variable as well as an input variable to a model. Also, if there are any exploratory data analysis methods for such variables.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "observe" a range? Making multiple observations and recording only their range may be conceptualized, modeled, and analyzed differently than, say, making a single observation of an *interval* value (as occurs in many kinds of censoring, for instance or in recording binned values like age groups). I find your suggestion to treat (possibly overlapping) ranges as "ordinal variables" to be particularly confusing because I see neither how it would be done nor what, if any, advantage it might have for data analysis.

Comment: @whuber, I meant observing an interval value, similar to age-groups one can have salary-ranges and here, I am assuming the ranges to be non-overlapping (and hence treating them as ordinal). The other case where range values are observation specific, I meant the end values are decided by the user and hence may or may not overlap. I am sorry for not being able to put this succinctly. Let me know if this is now clear.

Comment: Your second case often is fundamentally different from the first: there may be an association between the endpoints chosen by the user and other variables; this possibility should be part of the modeling and the analysis. Such situations also occur when variables are binned in a *post hoc* manner based on their values. At a minimum that causes a loss of "degrees of freedom" in statistical tests. In your first case, I still see no good reason to recommend treating binned values as ordinal solely because they are binned.

Comment: Are you looking for ordinal regression, or is that too obvious? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression

Comment: @whuber, I was thinking, non-overlapping ranges was a good enough reason to resort to treating it as ordinal variable. 

Peter Ellis, I don't think Ordinal regression can handle the case of overlapping ranges.

Comment: I we may have different conceptions of what an "ordinal" variable is. When data are binned or otherwise *expressed* as intervals, that does not necessarily make them ordinal: it merely limits their precision. Not only can such data still be compared (provided their ranges do not overlap), but the *values* represented by the ranges maintain whatever meanings they originally had: if originally differences or ratios of those values made sense, then differences and ratios of the interval-valued expressions make equal sense. You seem to rule this out by *fiat,* creating an unnecessary restriction.

Answer (score 5):

In Stata, both cases can be handled with the interval regression command [`intreg`](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rintreg.pdf), which is generalization of the Tobit. It can handle point, interval, or left/right censored data (or a mixture of them all). It does assume error term normality, but the log transformation can often work if your data require and permit it.

I am not sure if there are canned non-Stata implementations, but there are formulas and references at the end of the manual link. It is a fairly straight-forward likelihood function that should be fairly easy to maximize. There's also a nice comparison between the ordered probit approach and interval regression using the value of the log likelihood for the first case scenario.

Here's a very simple simulation with $N=5000, Y=\alpha + \beta \cdot X + \varepsilon =\frac{1}{2} + 1 \cdot X + \mathcal{N}[0,1]$:

```
#delimit;
clear all;

set seed 10011979;
set obs 5000;

gen x = rnormal();
gen ystar = 0.5 + 1*x + rnormal();
gen ylb = ystar - int((5-1)*runiform());
gen yub = ystar + int((5-1)*runiform());

intreg ylb yub x;
```

Every observation has a variable interval constructed by adding/subtracting a random uniform number to the true value, so the intervals may overlap. The data basically looks like this:

[image: First 10 Observations]

As you can see, 2 observations are uncensored (i.e., point data).

The output is:

```
Interval regression                               Number of obs   =    5000
                                                  LR chi2(1)      =    2102.49 
Log likelihood = -3580.5326                       Prob > chi2     =     0.0000


------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |    .979912   .0192016    51.03   0.000     .9422775    1.017546
       _cons |   .4757097   .0190327    24.99   0.000     .4384063    .5130131
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    /lnsigma |   .0336532   .0143186     2.35   0.019     .0055893    .0617171
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       sigma |   1.034226   .0148086                      1.005605    1.063661
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Observation summary:         0  left-censored observations
                             326     uncensored observations
                               0 right-censored observations
                            4674       interval observations
```

It seems like all the parameters, including the standard deviation of the error, are fairly close to the true values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked out the link you've mentioned, just based on examples provided, it seems this command only allows interval response variables with non-overlapping range. Do you happen to know whether this is true? Any references?

Comment: Just to add, I am interested in analyzing interval data variable in general, not just as a response variable..

Comment: The examples in the manuals are usually simple. In any case, I added an example that I hope is convincing. If you want the interval variable on the right hand side, I would try to enter them as a set of dummies. Obviously this will only work with a coarser interval scheme since you can't have a dummy for every observation.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for interval regression: In R you can use the survival package as explained  [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/intreg.htm)

Or you can try with the [intReg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/intReg/intReg.pdf) package using the intReg function

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked out both the packages. Just based on examples provided, it seems survival package only allows interval response variables with non-overlapping range. The intReg package though does seem to allow arbitrary user specific interval variables.

Comment: Just to add, I am interested in analyzing interval data variable in general, not just as a response variable..

Comment: Using interval data as a predictor seems more conflictive since you are introducing measurement error with each observation.

Comment: Yes, every observation will have measurement error, but i think, it's better to somehow incorporate such variables rather than not using them at all.