# How can I estimate the shape of a curve where the predictor variable is right censored interval variable?

Tags: distributions, ordinal-data, curve-fitting, interval-censoring

Are there methods available to conduct interval-regression style analysis where a predictor variable is the interval variable and the outcome variable is a dichotomous variable?

To give a bit of background, I would like to plot the relationship between two variables in a dataset where the x axis is a continuous measure has been collected in an ordinal format. The category widths are non-uniform (and increasing). To give a concrete example, the categories are about expenditure on a category of goods and were (in dollars): 0-50; 51-100; 101-250; 251-500; 501-1000; > 1000. The y-axis is a yes/no style variable.

I am particularly interested in determining whether the relationship is likely to be linear or exponential.

Are there any methods for doing this, other than arbitrarily picking a point in each x-axis category? Obviously, the final category (> 1000) is the most problematic. Bonus points (metaphorically speaking) if you can point me in the direction of an R package.

If it helps, I am happy to look for an answer that requires a strong distributional assumption (e.g. that the data are zero-inflated gamma or log-normal distributed).

Comment: See synonymous examples of [*interval regression*](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/65184/1036).

Comment: Thanks @AndyW . To reframe my question, is there a way to do logistic regression where the predictor variable is a right censored and categorised into variable width non-overlapping intervals?

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen any examples of generalized linear models with interval censored data like this. I would start with *Experimental uncertainty estimation and statistics for data having interval uncertainty* ([Ferson et al., 2007](http://prod.sandia.gov/techlib/access-control.cgi/2007/070939.pdf)) and see if you can track down any references. Interval censored is the key word you want to look for. The biostatistics community deals with it (e.g. contraction of a disease between doctor visits) so it may have been covered in that lit. somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @AndyW, I've posted my preferred solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the problem of regression with an interval-censored independent variable is much less studied than regression with an interval-censored dependent variable. There are at least a dozen studies on this topic, but as an applied researcher with limited mathematical statistics, I found few of them accessible.

An exception to this is [a recent paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1037/a0034274) in *Psychological Methods* by Timothy R. Johnson and Michelle M. Wiest. In line with a number of other researchers, they frame interval censoring as a type of missing data problem. Unlike other papers which demonstrate methods that are daunting to implement, Johnson and Wiest provide a number of JAGS model specifications in an appendix which can be modified to suit the problem at hand. Their methods are extensible to all generalised linear models with interval-censored and/or top-coded covariates.